# forEachTileCoord() returning wrong y coordinate

Tags: openlayers

I'm using this function to get all the coordinates in the tiles of my view, with my current zoom. I'm doing this way:

```js
...
this.map.getLayers().forEach((layer) => {
    if (layer.get('name') === 'randomLayer') {
        let extent = this.map.getView().calculateExtent(this.map.getSize());
        let zoom = this.map.getView().getZoom();

        layer.getSource().tileGrid.forEachTileCoord(extent, i, tileCoord => {
            console.log(tileCoord);
        });
    }
});
```

This is how the tiles are loaded in my view (z/x/y), with zoom 12:

```
12/1474/2376    12/1475/2376    12/1476/2376
12/1474/2377    12/1475/2377    12/1476/2377
12/1474/2378    12/1475/2378    12/1476/2378
```

And this is what is returned from the function:

```
12/1474/2377    12/1475/2377    12/1476/2377
12/1474/2378    12/1475/2378    12/1476/2378
12/1474/2379    12/1475/2379    12/1476/2379
```

The first row of coordinates, which are in the top of the screen, are not returned and the bottom row (2379) that aren't even in the view is returned. Is this intentional? Maybe am I delimiting the extent in the wrong way?

I'm also tried to get the extent as `this.map.getView().calculateExtent();`, but the same happens.

---

- [forEachTileCoord()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_tilegrid_TileGrid-TileGrid.html)
- [calculateExtent()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html)

---

As a workaround I can do the following:

```js
...
layer.getSource().tileGrid.forEachTileCoord(extent, i, tileCoord => {
    let z = Math.abs(tileCoord[2]) - 1;
});
```

But this doesn't seem quite right to do.

Comment: If you are using OpenLayers 5 or earlier and your y values are negative https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/canvas-tiles.html that is expected (as noted on the example "To calculate the y for a standard XYZ tile coordinate, use -y - 1") But OpenLayers 6 uses the same system as XYZ https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/canvas-tiles.html

Comment: I'm using OL5 with OSM from 'ol/source.js' and with BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps'. I'm loading them the default way, as presented in [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html). So, if I use the workaround it will be okay?

Comment: Until version 6 the workaround was the normal procedure as OpenLayers grids were numbered upwards while XYZ source were numbered downwards.  It is expained in the upgrade notes https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.0.0 under "New internal tile coordinates".

Comment: Very nice to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mike mentioned in the comments to my question, the workaround method I suggested at the end of the question is the method conventionally used for acquiring tile coordinates before version 6 of OpenLayers. The newer versions don't need to do this to get the same results.

@Mike:

> If you are using OpenLayers 5 or earlier and your y values are
>   negative that is
>   expected. But OpenLayers 6 uses the same
>   system as XYZ.
>   Until version 6 the workaround was the normal procedure as OpenLayers
>   grids were numbered upwards while XYZ source were numbered downwards.
>   It is expained in the upgrade notes
>   under "New
>   internal tile coordinates".

[Mentioned example](https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/canvas-tiles.html)

[Mentioned upgrade notes](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.0.0)